# EVP_PKEY_decryptにおいてSegmentation faultが発生します

Tags: c++, c, openssl

現在、C++でOpenSSLライブラリを用いて公開鍵暗号方式の暗号化、復号を実装しています。
しかし、プログラムを実行すると、以下の中の2回目のEVP_PKEY_decryptでSegmentation faultが発生します。
OSはUbuntu 14.04.3、コンパイラは<del>clang++-3.6または</del>clang++-3.8です。

```
bool decryptData(EVP_PKEY *key, unsigned char *data, size_t datalen, unsigned char **decdata, size_t *declen) {
    int ret;
    EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(key, NULL); // 鍵はRSA

    if ((ret = EVP_PKEY_decrypt_init(ctx)) != 1) {
        std::cerr << "init: " << ret << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    if ((ret = EVP_PKEY_decrypt(ctx, NULL, declen, data, datalen)) != 1) { 
        std::cerr << "dec1: " << ret << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    *decdata = (unsigned char *)realloc(*decdata, sizeof(unsigned char *) * *declen);
    //*decdata = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char *) * *declen);
    if ((ret = EVP_PKEY_decrypt(ctx, *decdata, declen, data, datalen)) != 1) { // <--
        std::cerr << "dec2: " << ret << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
        return true;
}
```

valgrindで見てみると以下のようになります。

```
==21343== Invalid read of size 8
==21343==    at 0x4EFF421: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==21343==    by 0x4F047B6: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==21343==    by 0x402FC9: decryptData(evp_pkey_st*, unsigned char*, unsigned long, unsigned char**, unsigned long*) (pubkeyenc.h:53)
==21343==    by 0x40323E: main (tmp.cpp:27)
==21343==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

decryptData()の引数の変数のアドレスはすべて0でないことを確認したのですが、このようなエラーになるのはどういった原因が考えられるのでしょうか？
どうぞよろしくお願いします。

---

### 追記:

呼び出し側は以下のようなコードで，encryptDataはdecryptData内のdecryptをencryptになっただけです．

```
int main() {
    unsigned char msg[] = "hoge";ただ
    unsigned char *enc = nullptr;
    //unsigned char *enc = NULL;
    size_t *enclen = (size_t *)malloc(sizeof(size_t));
    EVP_PKEY *key = /* 鍵を入れる関数 */
    if (key == nullptr) cerr << "priv key error" << endl;
    if(!(encryptData(key, msg, strlen(reinterpret_cast<char *>(msg)), &enc, enclen))) {
        cerr << "enc error" << endl;
    }else {
        cerr << "enc success" << endl;
    }

    unsigned char *decoded = nullptr;
    //unsigned char *decoded = NULL;
    size_t *declen = (size_t *)malloc(sizeof(size_t));
    key = /* 鍵を入れる関数 */
    if (key == nullptr) cerr << "pub key error" << endl;
    if(!(decryptData(key, enc, *enclen, &decoded, declen))) {
        cerr << "dec error" << endl;
    }else {
        cerr << "dec success" << endl;
    }   

    free(enclen);
    free(declen);
    if (enc != nullptr) free(enc);
    if (decoded != nullptr) free(decoded);

    return 0;
}
```

---

### 追記 (2016/12/19):

暗号化に用いる鍵はPEM_read_PrivateKeyを用いて，ssh-keygenで作成した秘密鍵を利用し，復号に用いる鍵はPEM_read_PUBKEYを用いて，ssh-keygenで作成した公開鍵を利用していました．
しかし，これらを逆にして公開鍵で暗号化し，秘密鍵で復号したところ問題なくプログラムが動きました．

Comment: `decryptData` を呼び出している側のコードは、どうなっていますか。

Comment: ```encryptDate()``` のコードはどうなってますか? ```enc``` は nullptr になっていませんか。

Answer (score 1):

> Address **0x0** is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

なので`nullptr`から値を読み込もうとしています。OpenSSL側のバグの可能性もありますが、たぶん不正な値を渡したのでしょう。

挙げられたコードを手直しして実行してみましたが特に問題なく動作しました。

---

なお、`enclen` `declen`は`size_t*`とする必要はありませんし、

```
*decdata = (unsigned char *)realloc(*decdata, sizeof(unsigned char *) * *declen);
```

では要求されたメモリ量の８倍のメモリ確保をしています。

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < *declen; ++i) {  
    *((unsigned char *)*decdata+i) = i & 0x1f;  
    printf("%02x", *((unsigned char *)*decdata+i));  
    *((unsigned char *)*decdata+i) = 0;  
    if ((i & 0x1f) == 0x1f) printf("\n");  
}`  
このような確認用のコードを，`if ((ret = EVP_PKEY_decrypt(ctx, *decdata, declen, data, datalen)) != 1) {`の前に入れて確認した結果，  
値が書き込めていたので，読んだり書いたりできる問題の無いポインタなのではと思います．